# meaning of notation of the set [a,b]×[c,d]?

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to understand what the set  [a,b]×[c,d] means I tried searching it on google but there is nothing I can find.can someone please explain it to me using this example  A = ([−1, 1] \ {0}) × [−1, 1].

Comment: Search for "cartesian product"

Comment: In this context, square braces here imply closed intervals of real numbers.  $\times$ here is a cartesian product. 
 $[a,b]\times [c,d]$ is then the filled rectangle including the boundary with vertices $(a,c),(a,d),(b,c),(b,d)$.  The example $([-1,1]\setminus \{0\})\times [-1,1]$ is the filled rectangle with corners $(-1,-1),(1,-1),(-1,1),(1,1)$ having removed the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$[a,b]\times [c,d]$ means all of the points $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 $ such that $a \leq x\leq b$ and $c\leq y \leq d$.
Using your example, it would be the set $\left\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | -1\leq x \leq 1, -1\leq y \leq 1 , x\neq 0\right\}$.

Answer (score 1):

If $A$ and $B$ are sets, then the *Cartesian product* of $A$ and $B$ is defined as,

$$A \times B:=  \{ (a,b): a \in A \text{ and } b \in B \}.$$

Therefore,

$$[a,b] \times [c,d] = \{\text{ pairs } (x,y): x \in [a,b] \text{ and } y \in [c,d] \}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Runso answered perfectly.

I just want to add, if you graphed in on an $xy$ plane it would be all the points inside a rectangle (centered at the origin and extending for $(-1,1)$ in the upper left to $(1,-1)$ in the lower right), but with the line $x=0$ (a vertical line contained in the $y$ axis) removed from the rectangle.